# Linq query order by giving me issues

Tags: sql, linq

I have a stored procedure that I wrote in SSMS using joins, show below

```
select distinct z.size, z.SortID 
from [ProductAttributes] x 
join [Product] y on x.ProductID = y.ProductID 
join [ProductSort] z on x.Size = z.Size 
where x.ProductID = @productID 
order by z.SortID
```

When I execute it returns the values I want and orders them by sortID, which I later supply to a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC.

I have since then wrote the stored procedure query using linq, shown below

```
var sizes = (from x in db.ProductAttributes
             join y in db.Products on x.ProductID equals y.ProductID
             join z in db.ProductSorts on x.Size equals z.Size
             where x.ProductID == productID
             orderby z.SortID 
             select x.Size).Distinct();
```

The problem is using this linq statement, it is not putting the data in the correct order, I am trying to order the dropdown list by sizes M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL, but it is returning L, M, XL, XXL, XXXL, so I am assuming it is ordering the data alphabetically.

If you look at the regular SQL statement the beginning of the query has 2 items after the select clause, can I not do this same thing in linq.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you try ordering it by x.Size.SortID instead of z.SortId?
if not, please provide the db tables included in this query

Comment: No I just tried that it it does not work, I noticed if I remove Distinct(), is sorts right, but it has every size multiple times for every item in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this case I would force the ordering after the query.

Here are a couple of ways to do it.

```
var allPossibleSizesInCorrectOrder = new []
{
    "XXXS", "XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL",
};

var ordering =
    allPossibleSizesInCorrectOrder
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .ToDictionary(xn => xn.x, xn => xn.n);

var sizes =
(
    from x in db.ProductAttributes
    join y in db.Products on x.ProductID equals y.ProductID
    join z in db.ProductSorts on x.Size equals z.Size
    where x.ProductID == productID
    select x.Size
)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray()
    .OrderBy(x => ordering[x])
    .ToArray();
```

This ignores sorting on the database and does an in memory sort based on the order of the `allPossibleSizesInCorrectOrder` array.

You could also do it this way:

```
var sizes =
(
    from x in db.ProductAttributes
    join y in db.Products on x.ProductID equals y.ProductID
    join z in db.ProductSorts on x.Size equals z.Size
    where x.ProductID == productID
    select new { x.Size, z.SortID }
)
    .ToArray()
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortID)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Size)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
    .Select(x => x.Size)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity and also Ahmad Hammoud for the help. Enigmativity would have an explaination to why doing it this way worked, the second example or where I can find some good readings on this.

Comment: @PsyChotic - The reason that both of these work is that they bring the data into memory before doing the sort - that's the first `.ToArray()` in each. Once it is in memory then it is pure LINQ and the database no longer can affect the results. Keep in mind that everything before the first `.ToArray()` doesn't execute as LINQ - it's translated into SQL first and often the SQL isn't the exactly same as the LINQ.

Comment: @PsyChotic - Try downloading LINQPad, if you don't already use it. It's a fabulous tool for coding (especially against databases) and will help you to learn what's going on in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Solution

Try Ordering it after the select:

```
var sizes = (from x in db.ProductAttributes
                     join y in db.Products on x.ProductID equals y.ProductID
                     join z in db.ProductSorts on x.Size equals z.Size
                     where x.ProductID == productID
                     select x.Size).Distinct();
sizes = sizes.OrderBy(x=>x.Size.SortID); //x.Size.SortID should be your sort ID.
```

I don't know the relations between your tables, so try to follow my code with your own implementation.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `SortID` is a property of `Size`?

Comment: I told you I don't know your tables, but you have Size, don't you have a reference between SortID and Size?

Comment: I'm not the OP, I was just commenting on your answer. From what I can see `.Size` is a string so it doesn't have a `.SortID` property.